# Can CocoaPods pod a library build by cMake with another cMake dependencies?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, cocoapods

I have a library build with cMake, and use cMake manage third party dependencies(use FetchContent);

Library has a podspec file that use framework for another proj needed use, but i wanna debug it in local, seems change the local podspec is easy:

```
...
  spec.prepare_command = <<-CMD
                    mkdir -p build/ios && cd build/ios
                    cmake ../.. -GXcode -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./
                    cmake --build . --target install -j 20
                 CMD
...
```

Unfortunately, i found out podspec files needs the spec.sources to list sources file which i already specify in cMake, is there a way CocoaPods use cmake generate xcodeproject directly, or another way that can resolve xcodeproj dependency with library build by cMake?